# Alpha-beta pruning with transposition tables

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, artifactory, alpha-beta-pruning, negamax

I don't get why flags for table entries are used as they are. Consider e.g. the pseudocode for [Negamax with alpha-beta pruning and transposition tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negamax#Negamax_with_alpha_beta_pruning_and_transposition_tables) and concentrate on the TT parts.

```
(* Transposition Table Lookup; node is the lookup key for ttEntry *)
ttEntry := transpositionTableLookup(node)
if ttEntry is valid and ttEntry.depth ≥ depth then
    if ttEntry.flag = EXACT then
        return ttEntry.value
    else if ttEntry.flag = LOWERBOUND then
        α := max(α, ttEntry.value)
    else if ttEntry.flag = UPPERBOUND then
        β := min(β, ttEntry.value)

    if α ≥ β then
        return ttEntry.value
```

That's OK. If entry contains the lower bound of the exact value we try to shrink the window from the left, etc.

```
(* Transposition Table Store; node is the lookup key for ttEntry *)
ttEntry.value := value
if value ≤ alphaOrig then
    ttEntry.flag := UPPERBOUND
else if value ≥ β then
    ttEntry.flag := LOWERBOUND
else
    ttEntry.flag := EXACT
ttEntry.depth := depth  
transpositionTableStore(node, ttEntry)
```

And this part I don't understand. Why we set UPPERBOUND flag if *value* was too small? *value* is on the left side of the search window -- it's smaller than the known lower bound -- *alpha*. So it seems that *value* should be a LOWERBOUND.

I'm certainly wrong with that logic, as it seen from my tests and the fact that everyone using that version. But I don't get why.

Comment: There is a very interesting discussion on exactly this topic on your referenced wikipedia page: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Negamax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Negamax)

Comment: @TheSlater, thanks, that's an interesting discussion. At first I made the same bogus "optimization" as a stubborn guy there. It's also amusing that widely cited text by Carolus contains a mistake which arises form bogus logic from my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the second thought, the question is trivial :)

Indeed, if the child node value was too good to cause a beta-cutoff (*value ≥ β*), it means that parent node has move that is at lest good as *value*, but maybe there are some even better move. So the *value* is the LOWERBOUND for the exact node value.

*value ≤ alphaOrig* means that all moves was worse than *alphaOrig*. That means that *value* is the UPPERBOUND of consequences of all moves.

Lower and Upper are bounds of the value of the current node, not the root one, as I somehow implied.